# Partial dependence plot, GBM multinomial

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, multinomial-distribution, boosting

I'm using *gbm* package to create a gradient boosting model with multinomial family. I have problems in plotting and interpreting partial dependence plots with this type of models.

an example:

```
library(gbm)
data(iris)
GBM.model = gbm(Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = iris,distribution = "multinomial")
plot.gbm(GBM.model, "Petal.Length")
```

I get the following plot:
[image]

Could you help me to improve the plot and interpret it? I think it should have a line for each category of the response variable but I'm not sure. Is there another way of getting partial dependence plots for multinomial gbm models?
I would appreciate any help with this

Comment: Welcome to CV.SE. Your intuition that we should have a line for each category of the response variable is correct. (+1) Please see my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is worth mentioning here that currently (Sep 2020) the `gbm` clear warns: `Setting 'distribution = "multinomial"' is ill-advised as it is currently broken. It exists only for backwards compatibility. Use at your own risk.`

In any case, we can get partial dependency plot through the package `pdp`. For example:
`partial(GBM.model, "Petal.Length", n.trees=100, which.class = 2, plot = TRUE, prob = TRUE))`. Please note the `which.class` argument. If we do not supply it, we get only for class 1 (`setosa`).

To that extent, based on the graph you have attached we can tell you what is going on (wrong) with the `gbm.plot`. The function appears to have plotted all three class-specific partial dependency plots at the same graph *and* having connected the end of each class-specific PDP with the start of the next class' PDP. That is why we have these long straight lines from (7,-10) to (1,0) and then from (-7,-2) to (-3,1); we connect the PDPs. Finally please note that when plotting PDPs for classification it is usually more informative to plot the PDPs on the probability (i.e. the response) scale. The (-10,10) scale of the y-axis corresponds to the value on the logistic scale and while informative it is less obvious what is the impact on the final classification.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! exploring the _pdp_ package I see that if I change the which.class argument to which.class=c(1,2,3) all the classes are plotted. Do you know how to add a legend to identify each category? thank you

Comment: If we want to have more customised plot I think the easier path is to pass the output of `partial` to an object *without* printing it directly (i.e. have `plot = FALSE`) and then using standard R functionality through `legend` to put the legend we would need, etc. If this answer is helpful please consider upvoting it and if it resolves your question marking it as the accepted answer.